# How to position exponent at same height in numerator and denominator?

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, fractions

I usually use `parbox` to make one expression the size of another but it doesn't seem to work in case of these fractions.

#### Fraction 1:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[draw]
            {%
                $%
                    \begin{gathered}
                        \frac{2^{-2}}{1}
                    \end{gathered}
                $
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Fraction 2:

Replace content's of `gathered` environment with `\frac{1}{2^{-2}}`

#### Output (Numerator's exponent is higher than denominator's):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise the exponent in the denominator by a simple `\mathpalette` trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bfrac}[2]{%
  \frac{#1}{\mathpalette\uncrampeddenominator{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\uncrampeddenominator}[2]{#1#2}

\begin{document}

X
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw]{%
    $\begin{gathered}
    \bfrac{2^{-2}}{1}
    \end{gathered}$%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw]{%
    $\begin{gathered}
    \bfrac{1}{2^{-2}}
    \end{gathered}$%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw]{%
    $\begin{gathered}
    \frac{1}{2^{-2}}
    \end{gathered}$%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
X

\bigskip

X
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw]{%
    $\begin{gathered}
    \bfrac{2^{-2}}{1^{\vphantom{-2}}}
    \end{gathered}$%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw]{%
    $\begin{gathered}
    \bfrac{1^{\vphantom{-2}}}{2^{-2}}
    \end{gathered}$%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
X

\end{document}
```

However the two fractions have different size and only phantoms would equalize them.

In the first row I present the final result with `\bfrac` and, for comparison, the version with `\frac`.

In the second row you see the equalized fractions.

[image]

Comment: +1 just to comment that the `\textrm` in my answer with package `amsmath` boils down to very similar thing as via `\text@` it goes through a `\mathchoice` like `\mathpalette` in your macro.

Comment: you may hypothetically need some `\firstchoice@false` added somewhere, if the exponents are obtained via macros manipulating counters ;-)

Comment: @jfbu Possibly, but this isn't a priority.

Answer (score 5):

You can force the numerator to adopt the cramped style of the denominator, with the help of mathtools package.

[image]

You can also convince the denominator not to use a cramped style; perhaps my way is overly complicated, but it works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\frac{2^{-2}}{1}\frac{1}{2^{-2}}\cramped{\frac{2^{-2}}{1}}$

\makeatletter

$\frac{2^{-2}}{1}\frac{1}{\mbox{\m@th\let\f@size\sf@size$2^{-2}$}}\frac{2^{-2}}{\mbox{\m@th\let\f@size\sf@size$1^{\vphantom{-2}}$}}$
\end{document}
```

---

An alternative approach to "uncramping" is to use `\textrm` (or `\textnormal`) macro.

```
$\frac{2^{-2}}{1}\frac{1}{\textrm{$2^{-2}$}}\frac{2^{-2}}{\textrm{$1^{\vphantom{-2}}$}}$
```

It gives exactly same output as above. But it does need the `\m@th`. I removed it only because usually `\mathsurround` is vanishing dimension so we can avoid the `\makeatletter` and make it look simple.

(as a rule `\textrm` will inherit bold series or italic shape from surrounding text but we again go into math mode inside its argument, so that does not matter here to us.)

---

Some additional info. The method with `\textrm` works *only under the assumption that `amsmath` is loaded* !

Indeed (and I got destabilized at some point because I was looking at LaTeX's definition of `\textrm` and `\textnormal` and could not understand that they worked as above; but amsmath changes them!).

For example, consider this

```
$2^{\textrm{3}}$
```

Output with amsmath on left, without on right:

[image]
[image]

It is to be noted that `\textrm`, `\textnormal`,  etc... with `amsmath` loaded go (like `\text`)  via a `\mathchoice` thing, hence they typeset 4 times (display, text, script, subscript sizes). Hence the most efficient is to use my initially proposed approach, possibly abstracted into a macro to make it look nice and simple.

Comment: further the amsmath variants do an `\everymath {#1}` which is not of the best style, as it (locally) overwrites the actual contents of `\everymath` with what it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `minimum height` option :

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
% \usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw, minimum height=1cm]
  {%
    $%
    \begin{gathered}
      \frac{2^{-2}}{1}
    \end{gathered}
    $
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node[draw, minimum height=1cm]
  {%
    $%
    \begin{gathered}
      \frac{1}{2^{-2}}
    \end{gathered}
    $
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can we somehow make exponents appear at the same height in both fractions?

Comment: @bp2017 I do not understand want you mean. Could you edit the question with an image of what you want.

Comment: look at the -2 in both fractions. It's higher in numerator than in denominator and that's the problem. Although your answer properly raises the drawing box of the second fraction, it also raises denominator with it (higher than it's supposed to be compared to the first fraction's denominator level).